# Social Sites - Cannot see Linked in link in the list of Social site buttons

Tags: social-content

I am adding LinkedIn for the My Social Accounts and Contacts in Accounts Detail page.
But the button does not appear.
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try checking under the Contact associated with that Account ?

Comment: Yes it appears under contact. How would I add it to the account detail page? Is that possible?

Comment: I have no idea why LinkedIn is not shown at account level. I checked in my dev org as well and it shows only at contact level :-(